# Laravel images not shown in any browser while firefox throwing "Image x cannot be displayed because it contains errors" error

Tags: linux, laravel, apache, ubuntu, firefox

My laravel app's images are not being shown in Firefox Chrome or Edge
Firefox shows a more explicit error saying "The image [image] cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

ie: the following image is not being shown:

http://test-gestion.pedifacil.com/storage/app/public/1/logo_196_196.png

but a txt in the same folder is being shown so it does not seem to be problem of wrong symlink

http://test-gestion.pedifacil.com/storage/app/public/1/hola.txt

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Note: Pagespeed has already been disabled in apache.

Note2: Apache error log is not showing anything related to this.

Note3: The same image put in the htdocs/ folder does not fail. See:
http://test-gestion.pedifacil.com/logo_196_196.png so does not seem to be related to an apache global malfunctioning

How can I get to know what is causing the error?
Thank you.

Comment: are these images by any chance converted base64 images? also would be helpful if we can see some code.

Comment: @bobby axe Thanks, would you like tosee the code for any specific part of laravel? the framework itself is huge.

Comment: Added note3. Could this be related to laravel /storage settings?

Comment: i feel that the image is not being saved correctly eg: some manipulations are performed on the image before it is saved?

Comment: The image in htdocs/ mentioned in note3 is just a cp of the original image, so the file format seems to be correct. The original was uploaded into laravel media library using the regular form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

- Put back the laravel public/ folder in the root of the laravel app
  path (/opt/bitnami/apache2/laravel_app/public/)
- Then created an apache "/l/" alias  pointing to /opt/bitnami/apache2/laravel_app/public/
- Update the .env file for updating the app url to "http://example.com/l/"